# std::invoke_result doesn't work in a template function with auto return type

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to use `std::invoke_result_t` and it fails when called for nested lambda in function with `auto` return type. Here is a reproducer:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto print_ret_type(T &&t, Args &&... args) {
  using ret_type = std::invoke_result_t<T, Args...>;
  std::cout << typeid(ret_type).name() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  auto worker = [](int i) {
    auto worker_impl = [](int i, auto &worker) {
      print_ret_type(worker, i, worker);
    };
    worker_impl(i, worker_impl);
  };
  worker(10);

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
include/c++/9.3.0/type_traits:2783:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::invoke_result<(lambda at test.cpp:13:24) &, int &, (lambda at test.cpp:13:24) &>'
    using invoke_result_t = typename invoke_result<_Fn, _Args...>::type;
```

If I use `void` return type for `print_ret_type` instead of `auto` the test compiles successfully. There is a returned template structure in my original code, which depends on `ret_type`. Can anyone explain why I get an error when `auto` return type is used?

Comment: Having two variables called `worker` is making it a bit hard to tell what you actually want to do. Is `print_ret_type(worker, i, worker)` really referring to the lambda's second parameter twice?

Comment: @Frank Yes, it looks like a pseudo-Y-combinator

Comment: Yes, `worker` param (which is actually a reference to `worker_impl`) is used twice in the call. In my original code, `worker_impl` recursively calls itself and the second param is used for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules for how return type deduction work are a bit quirky.

To determine the return type, it actually instantiates the body of the function.  Any errors in this instantiation are hard errors.

Lambdas return types are implicitly `->auto` basically; so those rules apply to them.  If you want to know the return type of `worker`, *every line of worker must be instantiated*, and ditto for `worker_impl`.

```
auto worker = [](int i) {
  auto worker_impl = [](int i, auto &worker) {
    print_ret_type(worker, i, worker);
  };
  worker_impl(i, worker_impl); // << worker_impl has no return type yet
};
worker(10);
```

The return type is demanded in:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto print_ret_type(T &&t, Args &&... args) {
  using ret_type = std::invoke_result_t<T, Args...>;
```

this function is instantiated inside `worker_impl` to determine *its* return type in order to determine the return type of `worker_impl`.

Change it to add `->void` to `worker_impl`:

```
auto worker_impl = [](int i, auto &worker)->void {
```

and it compiles, or `print_ret_type` to return `void`.

Either one blocks the instantiation of the invoke result at a point where we don't know the return type of `worker_impl` yet.

---

Naively, the simple rule "no `return` statement, an `auto` return body returns `void`" would be what you'd think is used.  But C++ doesn't have that rule.

Return type deduction does not untangle all possible cases.  Sometimes you have to make the return type explicit.

And the rules for what happens when deducing return type are not as narrow as they could be.  While the return type of `print_ret_type` does not matter to the return type of `worker_impl`, the standard (out of generosity to compiler implementors) gets them to do something closer to "real compilation" there.